# For the 4/20 Launch of Starship does anyone know what was inside starship?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

I was curious to know if they built rooms or had dummies inside, or what they put in it to simulate weight.

Comment: No red Tesla this time in a new rocket.

Comment: Since it was launched on 4/20 I suppose it was filled with weed

Comment: @ThisIsNicola We'll know when all the fast food places downwind of the explosion post a sudden spike in sales...

Comment: It was not planned to have any payload, but just after launch, it decided to take several chunks of the concrete below the OLM aboard as souvenirs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There was no indication of any payload aboard Ship 24.  Definitely no rooms or dummies.  I haven't seen any documentation of a mass simulator, either, and much of the construction has been observed in detail, see e.g. [this fandom.com wiki entry on Notable Differences between S24 and prior Starships](https://starship-spacex.fandom.com/wiki/Ship_24_(S24)#Notable_differences).

In the past SpaceX has publicly acknowledged mass simulators / boilerplate payloads on test launches, so unless they release some statement contradicting this, I think "no mass simulator was observed" is the best answer we'll have.

Supplementary quote from [Musk's post-flight Twitter Space](https://youtu.be/mmIqSPux3FY?t=1516) (25m16s)

> **Elon Musk:**
>
> The goal of these early missions is just information.
> Like we don't have any payload or anything.
> It's let's try to learn as much as possible.

Comment: The payload door was welded shut so the only thing that could potentially be in there is something that fits through the tiny service hatches.

Comment: Given their (stated) main goal was to just get it off the launch pad, having any unnecessary weight is counter-productive.

Answer (score -4):

They had originally planned on putting Starlink v2 satellites inside but decided not to so the rack that holds and releases them was inside but no satellites. There was nothing else inside.

Comment: do you have any sources for that info?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).